# cannot convert 'b2PolygonShape' to 'objc_object*' in argument passing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I am not sure if many of you are familiar with the box2d physics engine, but I am using it within cocos2d and objective c.

This more or less could be a general objective-c question though, I am performing this:

```
NSMutableArray *allShapes = [[NSMutableArray array] retain]; 
b2PolygonShape shape;
..
..
[allShapes addObject:shape];
```

and receiving this error on the addObject definition on build:

```
cannot convert 'b2PolygonShape' to 'objc_object*' in argument passing
```

So more or less I guess I want to know how to add a b2PolygonShape to a mutable array.  b2PolygonShape appears to just be a class, not a struct or anything like that.  The closest thing I could find on google to which I think could do this is described as 'encapsulating the b2PolygonShape as an NSObject and then add that to the array', but not sure the best way to do this, however I would have thought this object should add using `addObject`, as some of my other instantiated class objects add to arrays fine.

Is this all because b2PolygonShape does not inherit `NSObject` at it's root?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b2PolygonShape` is a C++ class, not an ObjC class. You can only put ObjC instances into "NS-containers".

Since you need C++ anyway, it's better to use a `std::vector<b2PolygonShape>`.

Comment: Ok thanks, so something like this? std::vector<b2PolygonShape> shape; But now how can I use shape.m_vertexCount = [listOfPoints count]; like I had before? 'has no member' error.. sorry my c++ knowledge is pretty limited :(

Comment: @GONeale: No, I mean `std::vector<b2PolygonShape> allShapes; b2PolygonShape shape; ...; allShapes.push_back(shape);`. To get the `-count`, use `allShapes.size()`. There is documentation in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/. (Don't change the `m_vertexCount` directly, use the `Set` method.)

Comment: Thanks for that Kenny. Might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

NS-container classes can (as KennyTM pointed out) only store NSObjects. This can be a bit of a pain sometimes. But there are plenty of alternatives to NS-containers.

You can write Objective-C wrapper classes (or use NSValue), and store these in an NSArray.

You could use a plain old C array (though, that may not serve your needs, if the array size is undefined and shrinks and grows)

You could use a hash table to store your references.

A linked list of structs can also come in handy, and is fairly easy to create and maintain.

Should you decide to stick to std::vector, which is as good a solution as any, you can read more about that at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/

Comment: Yes, thanks I have discovered they are a bit frustrating:) But I have decided to go for a wrapper method for now (custom class exposing my C++ object), but I might look into the vector method.